# Regular expression to match not containing a word

Tags: regex, netbeans

Given these three JS function declaration text...

```
var fn3 = function(data){
  if (data)
  {
     alert('Yes data');
  }
}

var fn2 = function(data){
  if (nope)
  {
     alert('Nope');
  }
}

var fn3 = function(data){
  if (data)
  {
     alert('Yes data');
  }
}
```

... what regular expression can I use to match the function that DOES NOT contain the word "data" in its body?

For example, I want to match this string in fn2 above:

```
function(data){
  if (nope)
  {
     alert('Nope');
  }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using regular expressions to parse code, especially in JS because the regex does not support nested patterns. For instance, you get [this](https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/24) with the accepted answer's regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var [^{]*{((?!\bdata\b)[\s\S])*}
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/22

Comment: That's it! I'm missing the \b on my negative look ahead! Thank you kind stranger.